# Why are humbuckers not skew?

Tags: pick-ups

I'm curious why single coil pickups on strats are skew but humbukers seem to be level with the bridge?

[image: Humbuckers]

VS

[image: Single Coils]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bridge pickup is angled that way to slightly emphasise treble frequencies on the high strings, and bass frequencies for the low strings (for that pickup). It's not a design decision that use of a single coil pickup leads you to inevitably - for example, dynasonic pickups in a Grestch are straight:

[image: dynasonic pickups in a Grestch]

As are the single coils in Fender's own Jazzmaster and Jaguar:

[image: Jazzamster]
[image: jaguar]

One reason to not angle an older-style humbucker is that it would look awkward, due to the greater height - the strat pickup gets away with it aesthetically due to the rounded short edges and slim dimensions. Making a differently-shaped humbucker for angled mounting would mean greater manufacturing cost (The angled pickup on a strat is the same dimensions as the straight ones).

Another reason to mount humbuckers straight is that humbuckers aren't only chosen for hum rejection, but also when a warmer, bassier sound is desired. If that's a choice you've made, you may not want to negate it by having a twangier treble response.

It is possible to have a humbucker that will fit in the angled slot - such as [this product by diMarzio](http://www.dimarzio.com/pickups/strat/hum-canceling-strat/tone-zone-s):

[image: dimarzio tone zone pickup]

They seem to acknowledge that the response that comes from the angled mounting may not be desired, stating:

> We took into account the likelihood of installing The Tone Zone®
>   S in the classic slanted Strat® bridge position, warming up the higher
>   frequencies and brightening the low notes a little.

Comment: Has fender ever experimented with single coils that are straight? (In line with the bridge)

Comment: @NeilMeyer  added some pics of the Jazzmaster and Jaguar.

Comment: Sorry I mean specifically strats with a straight bridge pickups.

Comment: @NeilMeyer I've never seen it - there's a thread at http://www.strat-talk.com/threads/that-bridge-pickup-angle.28609/ where someone's felt the need to photoshop it!

Answer (score 0):

Fender actually recently designed some offset Squier models in the Paranormal series that have skew humbuckers. These are a bit weird-and-wacky, but it is the first time I saw it. I added the video to show you more details.

[Here is the breakdown on the one with the skew humbuckers](https://www.andertons.co.uk/squier-paranormal-super-sonic-ice-blue-metallic-0377015583)