# Slanted single coil pickups on Fender Stratocaster

Tags: electric-guitar, pick-ups, stratocaster

How does the sound produced from a slanted single coil pickup on a Fender Stratocaster differ from the regular non-slanted single coil pickups?

Comment: related https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/40696/why-are-humbuckers-not-skew

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closer the sound is picked up (or picked, for that matter) to the bridge, the more treble (top) is heard. So with a slanted pup, the treble is slightly more exaggerated than it is from a straight pup. That's it.